# How to use qt5_add_binary_resources in CMake to generate rcc files

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, rcc

I'm trying to create `rcc` files with `CMake`, using the `qt5_add_binary_resources(target inputfile ... OPTIONS ... DESTINATION ...)` [macro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html):

```
qt5_add_binary_resources(myApp "themes/redTheme.qrc" OPTIONS ARGS -binary)
```

Since I'm using other macros such as `add_executable` in my `CMakeLists` file (which asks for a `target`), I'm getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2013/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake:255 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target
  "myApp" because another target with the
  same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable created in
  source directory [..]
```

Note that my `CMakeLists` file is nested in a root `CMakeLists`.

**EDIT:** I took a look at the [definition](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake) (l.226) of the `qt5_add_binary_resources` macro. The last line is the command provoking my error. It doesn't seem to be doing anything:

`add_custom_target(${target} ALL DEPENDS ${rcc_destination})`

I don't understand why the macro needs a `target`?

**EDIT:** here's the content of my `CMakeLists.txt`, though simplified for clarity reasons.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.4)
CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0002 NEW)

PROJECT(myApp)

SET(RCC_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/bin/rcc.exe)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed
SET(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
SET(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Core 5.5.0 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets 5.5.0 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Qml 5.5.0 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Quick 5.5.0 REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# etc.

SET(myApp_LIBRARIES
    ${BOOST_THREAD_LIBRARIES}
    ${BOOSTALL_LIBRARIES}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::Quick
)

SET(myApp_LIBRARIES
        ${myApp_LIBRARIES}
)

SET(myApp_SOURCES
    source/main.cpp
)

SET(myApp_RESOURCES
    resources/qml.qrc
)

SET(myApp_EXTERNAL_BINARY_RESOURCES
    themes/redTheme.qrc
    themes/blueTheme.qrc
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(myApp WIN32
        ${myApp_SOURCES} ${myApp_RESOURCES}
)

FOREACH(_qrc_file ${myApp_EXTERNAL_BINARY_RESOURCES})
    STRING(REPLACE "qrc" "rcc" _rcc_file ${_qrc_file})
    # This is where I'd like to create my binary resources
    # QT5_ADD_BINARY_RESOURCES("test.rcc" ${_qrc_file})
    # Current working process, but not clean
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND ${RCC_EXECUTABLE} -binary ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_qrc_file} -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_rcc_file})
ENDFOREACH()
```

According to this file, I'm trying to generate two `rcc` files: `redTheme.rcc` and `blueTheme.rcc`.

Comment: Can you just change target file name for resource file? `qt5_add_binary_resources(resources "qml.qrc" OPTIONS ARGS -binary)` or something. And in the code of your application: QResource::registerResource("resources.rcc");

Comment: No I can't. I'm getting the same error: another `target` already exists.

Comment: Can you provide more code from your CMakeList file?

Comment: See updated original post. Note that this file is itself embedded within a root `CMakeLists` file (which is only setting variables and adding subdirectories).

Comment: In my case replacing FOREACH with `qt5_add_binary_resources("redTheme" "themes/redTheme.qrc" OPTIONS ARGS -binary)` works fine. And after running cmake I  got `redTheme.rcc` file in the same directory as the myApp binary.

Comment: `target` in qt5_add_binary_resources is just an argument name of this function.

Comment: You're right. However doing the same does not produce anything in my project. Two targets are created in my build configuration: http://i.imgur.com/1pGwXi0.png
Running `CMake` does not create the `rcc` files. My binary is located in the `Release` directory, could that be a problem (I'm using two build configurations)?

Comment: So, now cmake with qt5_add_binary_resources runs without an error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106948/discussion-between-gregoire-borel-and-tony-o).

Answer (score 0):

By the way... you don't need to pass "OPTIONS ARGS -binary" as it is defined already as binary.
You need to pass a target name because you can call "make targetname" to generate rcc file manually. Also the rcc file will be generated by "all" target and if you add it as a dependency to another target with add_dependeny.
The rcc file won't be generated at cmake configure time but on compile time. Also it will be re-generated if a file changed.

So you need to pass an unused target name as the error told you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the.rcc files rebuilt when their constituent files are modified, you must generate a list of dependencies. Also, using execute_process means the command is executed when cmake is run, not when the app is built, which is probably not what you want to.

```
# Get rcc command path and put it in RCC
get_target_property(RCC
    Qt5::rcc
    IMPORTED_LOCATION
)

# For each font file...
foreach(fnt IN LISTS FontResFile)

    # Generate dependencies
    execute_process (
        COMMAND "${RCC}" --list ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${fnt}.qrc
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE deps
    )

    # convert to a list and put in deps2
    string(REGEX REPLACE "\n" ";" deps2 "${deps}")

    # Add command to build font rcc file
    add_custom_command (
        OUTPUT ${UI_OUTPUT_DIR}/${fnt}.rcc
        COMMAND Qt5::rcc --binary ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${fnt}.qrc --compress 9 --threshold 10 -o ${UI_OUTPUT_DIR}/${fnt}.rcc
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${fnt}.qrc
        DEPENDS ${deps2}
        VERBATIM
    )
    add_custom_target (${fnt}_tgt DEPENDS ${UI_OUTPUT_DIR}/${fnt}.rcc DEPENDS ${deps2} )
    add_dependencies(my_target_name ${fnt}_tgt)
endforeach()
```